# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when creating SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make a game when a player touches screen, a gem is showing up on the screen, but I have an error Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. How to fix it?

I doing this:

```
var gem : SKSpriteNode!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with the event: UIEvent?) {

    gem = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "CoolGem")!
    gem.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    addChild(gem)
    gem.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: Double.random(in: -100...100), y: Double.random(in: -100...100)), duration: 1))

}
```

The error tells me this: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the 3rd line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the image added to your project? is it in an asset catalog?

if so try accessing it like so

```
gem = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Gem")
```

or you can ensure that it won't be nil

```
if let gem = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Gem") as? SKSpriteNode {
    self.gem = gem
    gem.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    addChild(gem)
    gem.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: Double.random(in: -100...100), y: Double.random(in: -100...100)), duration: 1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, there's no file named `CoolGem`. Since you used force unwrapping (!), the app crashes because your `gem` variable is nil.

Comment: I have a file called "Gem"

Comment: It still dont work

Comment: File needs to be named "CoolGem", not "Gem". That, or change the line where you look for the file named "CoolGem" into gem = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "Gem")!